# JQuery form of radio input

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I am trying to make a simple form of radio inputs where at most 1 can be selected:

```
<form id='forma' action='predmeti.php' method='GET'>
        1:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='1'/>
        2:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='2'/>
        3:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='3'/>
        <input type='button' id='ok' value='Izaberi godinu!'>
</form>
```

How do i allow form submit only if one is selected and prevent submit if nothing selected? The form is submited by clicking on the id='ok' button.

Comment: do you want it to submit automatically when one is checked? or you need to allow submit only if one is checked?

Comment: @MinaJacob not automatically, but when the button id='ok' is pressed, and exactly one of the radio's has to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated based on comment. Please try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#ok').on('click', function(){
        if($("#forma input[type='radio']:checked").length == 1){
            $(this).closest("form").submit();
        }
       });
    });
```

Comment: not on click of the radio, but on click of the button  under the radio's, the button with id='ok'

Comment: Updated  the answer based on the comment. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

add required attribute to one of the radio buttons, here is an example
http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/zBBzxo?editors=1010

```
<form id='forma' action='predmeti.php' method='GET'>
        1:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='1' required></input>
        2:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='2'></input>
        3:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='3'></input>
        <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way of doing it without the radios getting circled and the alert showing? I already have in mind what should happen

Comment: what's the scenario you have in mind when someone click submit and nothing checked?  what should happen?

Comment: i have a span tha is set to `display: none`; it changes to `display: inline`

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent default action using `event.preventDefault()`, `.is()` with parameter `:checked` to submit `form` if one of `[name=godina]` elements is checked

```js
$("input[type=button]").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("[name=godina]").is(":checked")) this.parentElement.submit()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form id='forma' action='' method='GET'>
        1:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='1'/>
        2:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='2'/>
        3:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='3'/>
        <input type='button' id='ok' value='Izaberi godinu!'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this updated link http://codepen.io/mozzi/pen/zBBzxo?editors=1010 it should do what you want

```
<form id='forma' action='predmeti.php' method='GET'>
  1:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='1' required></input>
  2:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='2'></input>
  3:<input type='radio' name='godina' value='3'></input>

  <span id="msg" style="display: none">hello world </span>
  <input type='button' id='ok' value='Izaberi godinu!'>
</form>

$('#ok').on('click', function() {
  if ($('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0) {
    $('#msg').css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $('#msg').css('display', 'inline');
  }

});
```